# Drawing Venn diagram to describe a real life process (problem with nonexistent intersection)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, applications

I'm going to ask my question by making a visual analogy. Say, I need to create (and describe) a Venn diagram to match a real life process.
Analogy ([pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCelO.png)): with time there are more and more **B**lack **C**ars and **B**lack **S**hirts in country *A* (people's love for this colour increases). One needs to emphasise that even though **visually** **C**ars and **S**hirts are going to intersect at some point – such a thing is not actually possible (as if they are not in the same dimension with one another); there is no way that 'shirtocar' or 'caroshirt' emerges. The main purpose of the diagram is to show this "transition of things to the black" trend.
How to modify a diagram to say this – if not possible, how should One articulate this process mathematically (also, is it blatantly wrong, for ex., to add a footnote under the diagram, that states C ∩ S = ∅,  while C *actually* ∩ S visually with some area in between)?

Comment: I cannot imagine how to draw a "static" diagram describing an "evolving" process...

Comment: Why not use two cartesian diagrams (x-axis=time vs y-axis=percentage) showing that the % of Black cars grows in time?

Comment: Thanks. I believe such a method (cartesian diagrams) obliges its applier to use more rigorous quantitative parameters, so to say. On the contrary, Venn diagrams, while conveying the main conceptual idea behind one’s visual model, bear some grain of subjectiveness, making it easier to describe and interpret.